# Cartesian equation for a transcendental / trigonometric curve

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations, transcendental-functions

[image: gourd curve]

Hello! Please see figure above. I am searching for the cartesian equation for the curve in green, similar to how the equation for a semicircle is $f(x) = √(1 - x^2)$. I'm not sure if this is even possible, so any feedback is appreciated. My several attempts have failed.

The construction is set up like so (upon a circle of radius=1):
$$\frac{m}{k} = \frac{k}{t}$$
or
$$\frac{sin(α)} {sin(β)} = \frac{sin(β)} {sin(α+β)}$$

As you can see, $x$ is in blue and $f(x)$ is in green, and as **α** grows, then the point **H** traces out the curve in green, which I'm calling a gourd curve. Is it possible to obtain a cartesian equation for the gourd curve and not something which contains trigonometric identities? Trigonometric identities are also welcome, but I'd prefer to analyze the equation without them.

Answer (score 1):

Relabelling your figure a bit, I'm taking center $O$, and points $A$ and $B$ on the circle with $M$ the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $\overline{OA}$. If the circle meets the $x$-axis at $R$, then define $\alpha :=\angle ROA$ and $\beta :=\angle AOB$.

[image]

If the radius of the circle is $r$, then we can write the coordinates of $M$ as
$$x = r \cos\beta \cos\alpha \qquad y = r\cos\beta \sin\alpha \tag1$$

The imposted relation on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is
$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{\sin\beta}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)} \tag2$$

Expanding $(2)$, and using the parameterizations
$$\cos\alpha=\dfrac{1-a^2}{1+a^2} \quad \sin\alpha=\dfrac{2a}{1+a^2} \quad
\cos\beta=\dfrac{1-b^2}{1+b^2} \quad \sin\beta=\dfrac{2b}{1+b^2} \tag3$$ we can use, say, the method of resultants to eliminate $a$ and $b$ to obtain this cartesian equation for the gourd curve:

> $$\begin{align}
> 0 &= (x^2 + y^2)^8 \\
>  &\quad- 2 r^2\, (x^2 + y^2)^5\, (2 x^4 + 3 x^2 y^2 + 3 y^4) \\
>  &\quad+\phantom{2}r^4\, (x^2 + y^2)^4\, (6 x^4 + 6 x^2 y^2 + 11 y^4) \\
>  &\quad- 2 r^6\, (x^2 + y^2)^2\, (2 x^6 + 3 x^4 y^2 + 5 x^2 y^4 + 3 y^6) \\
>  &\quad+\phantom{2}r^8\, ((x^2+y^2)^2 - x^2 y^2)^2
> \end{align} \tag{$\star$}$$

(This form was used to generate the figure above. Because $x$ and $y$ appear exclusively to even powers, the solution set includes a horizontally-mirrored copy of the gourd.)

In polar form (using $\rho$ for the radial variable since I'm using $r$ for the radius of the circle):

> $$\begin{align}
> 0 &= \rho^8 \\
> &\quad-2\rho^6 r^2\, (3 - 3 \cos^2\theta + 2 \cos^4\theta) \\
> &\quad+\phantom{2}\rho^4 r^4\,  (11 - 16 \cos^2\theta + 11 \cos^4\theta) \\
> &\quad-2 \rho^2 r^6\,  (3 - 4 \cos^2\theta + 2 \cos^4\theta + \cos^6\theta) \\
> &\quad+\phantom{2\rho^2} r^8\, (1 - \cos^2\theta + \cos^4\theta)^2
> \end{align} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

(Because $\rho$ appears exclusively to even powers, real roots occur in $\pm$ pairs; taking just one of these should give a single "gourd".)

Comment: Thank you, @Blue. It's amazing how something so simple can become so complicated! Are you saying that there's no way to get formula (*) into an f(x) = (...some equation just in terms of x) form? I'd gather that if so, it would be many times more complicated. Your diagram is lovely, btw. What program did you use to make it? Thx again!

Comment: @VinMilligan: Equation $(\star)$ is a degree-$8$ polynomial in $y^2$; anything above degree-$4$ is typically not solvable in any elementary way. The polar equation $(\star\star)$ is "only" quartic in $\rho^2$, so there *is* an explicit solution, but [it's ugly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). *Maybe* the triggy nature of the coefficients allows for some simplification, but I'm afraid my life priorities lie elsewhere. :) ... BTW: I use a desktop app version of [GeoGebra](https://geogebra.org) for my diagrams.

Comment: Thanks again, @Blue I also am using Geogebra, however I noticed that the function is breaking up around the xAxis. I tried using the polar form in Sagemath to graph it, and it can't because I think of this same problem. Maybe it's the "unwieldy" scale of the function. I'm tying to take my original diagram, the curve in green, and find the integral and/or arc length. Though, guessing on how insane this function is, I don't think it will be very clean. I can't find the integral if the function is falling apart at the xAxis. Anything I can do about that?

Comment: @VinMilligan: Implicit plots are notoriously problematic. The software typically doesn't see the *curve*, but only a collection of sampled points that (more-or-less) satisfy the relation. Parametric equations tend to be better, since —by design— they encode a graph *as a curve*. In your case, the polar form provides the merest glimmer of hope, since the quartic equation in $\rho^2$ has an explicit solution; however, expressing that solution and doing the appropriate Calculus with it —even numerically— would seem to be a nightmare. What's your interest in the curve? Just curiosity?

Comment: I see, you're right. I tried to format the polar equation, for solutions of your radius, or  rather, and it gave me an 8-headed hydra. As for my interest in the curve, it's too much to go into here, but I think there's something there for investigating the Riemann zeta function. It's a transcendental function incorporating one mean between two extremes, which is expressive of quadratic relationships. The next step would be to look at the cubic relationships and that curve, perhaps shedding light on the odd index values of the zeta function, in that case, apery's constant.